# Cannot trigger CKEditor WYSIWYG in form API

Tags: forms, wysiwyg

I’m using Drupal 7.18 with CKEditor 4.3 (full package), and trying to get a WYSIWYG field via the form API. My code:

```
function article_edit_form($form, &$form_state, $article)
{
    // ...

    return array(
        // ...
        'content'  => array(
            '#type'    => 'text_format',
            '#title'   => t('Content'),
            '#format'  => 'full_html',
            '#wysiwyg' => true,
            '#input_format' => '1',
            '#value'   => array(
                'value'  => is_null($article) ? '' : $article->content,
                'format' => 'full_html'
            )
        ),
        // ...
    );
}
```

But this only displays a regular `textarea` with a section to choose the “text format”. The CKEditor is installed, enabled and I’m logged as admin.

Comment: Is CKEditor enabled for `full_html`, not just `filtered_html`?

Comment: @Clive Yes it is.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that you could try changing:

- `#input_format` and `#wysiwyg` are not in the [list of available properties for a text_format element](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#text_format), so even if they're not causing the error, you should probably remove them.
- You shouldn't set the `#value` of an element like that (unless it's a `value` type itself). Instead you should use `#default_value`. In the case of a text_format the `#default_value` is expecting the text for the text area (since you've already set the format with `#format`).

I would expect this to work (certainly does for me if memory serves), but if not, check the console for JS errors

```
return array(
    // ...
    'content'  => array(
        '#type'    => 'text_format',
        '#title'   => t('Content'),
        '#format'  => 'full_html',
        '#default_value' => is_null($article) ? '' : $article->content
    ),
    // ...
);
```

Comment: The editor is still not showing.

Comment: Works perfectly for me, your problem must be somewhere else